# How awful is rendering a component in 3 different phases?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How awful is that :

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setWidth(ganttContainerRef.current.offsetWidth);
    setHeight(ganttContainerRef.current.offsetHeight);
  }, [])

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (width > 0) {
      setGanttReady(true);
    }
  }, [width])

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (ganttReady) {
      ganttRef.current.scrollTo({ left: 80 * 80 / 7 + 40 });
    }
  }, [ganttReady]);
```

i.e. rendering a component in 3 separate steps...

1. One to render the container (this container is built with %age, and
   I need the real width for step 2 and step 3)
2. One to render the text
   displayed in this container (need the text height for step 3)
3. One to
   render my gantt (all with a lot of absolute positions)

If I render 1 and 2 at the same time, the container width will be 0 (first render) because 2 is not displayed yet.
No matter what I do, if I do `const top = refs.current[initiative.id].offsetTop;`, `offsetTop` will have a value as if width was still 0. offsetTop is not updated with a rerender.

With the posted code above it works fine, but how awful is it?
Is it doable to render a component in multiple phases or am I really hacking normal React behaviour?

Comment: Where else are `width`, `height` and `ganttReady` used, where else are `setWidth` and `setGanttReady` called?

Comment: "How awful" isn't a good question for SO. Please revise to ask something more objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With the posted code above it works fine, but how awful is it? Is it
> doable to render a component in multiple phases or am I really hacking
> normal React behaviour?

I wouldn't say it is awful, you could say it is not very efficient, but I would not worry about it if it isn't noticeable.

You can refactor it to something like this:

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let offsetWidth = ganttContainerRef.current.offsetWidth;
    setWidth(offsetWidth);
    setHeight(ganttContainerRef.current.offsetHeight);

    if (offsetWidth > 0) {
      setGanttReady(true);
      ganttRef.current.scrollTo({ left: (80 * 80) / 7 + 40 });
    }
  }, []);
```

But the problem with this approach is as you can see it runs only on mount; which is Ok if that's what you want. So with your previous approach here:

```
 useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (width > 0) {
      setGanttReady(true);
    }
  }, [width])
```

you had the benefit that if `width` changed, then you could act on it, you don't get it with my version.
So it depends.